# add element with certain id from another file to data-layer= galleria

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, glob, galleria

I'm trying to create a slideshow (with Galleria) with an overlay or "html layer" to show text over the images. But I have loads of pages where it will be loaded so it should be dynamic (is that how you call it?) the overlay text should change depending on the folder where galleria will be loaded from.

this is the code i have and works fine for the "dynamic" loading of the images depending of the folder.

```
<div class="galleria">
<?php

//path to directory to scan
$directory = "./";

//get all image files with a .jpg extension.
$images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");

//print each file name
foreach($images as $image) {
  echo "<img src=\"$image\">";
}
?>
</div>
<script>
    Galleria.loadTheme('/galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
    Galleria.configure({
        showCounter: false,
    })
    Galleria.run('.galleria');
</script>
```

I think [galleria-data](http://support.galleria.io/kb/references/galleria-data) might be a solution, but can't get it to work..

```
<div class="galleria">
<?php

//path to directory to scan
$directory = "./";

//get all image files with a .jpg extension.
$images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");
//path to index file with needed text
$meas = glob($directory . "*.php");

//print each file name
foreach($images as $image) {
  echo "<img src=\"$image\"";
  echo " data-layer=\"$meas\">"; //only see "Array" written over the image
}
?>
</div>
<script>
    Galleria.loadTheme('/galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
    Galleria.configure({
        showCounter: false,
    })
    Galleria.run('.galleria');
</script>
```

Hope someone can help me, if needed I can provide more info.
Thanks in advance!!

Kind regards,
Stephen

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo " data-layer=\"$meas\">"; //only see "Array" written over the image
```

Try this:

```
 echo " data-layer=".$meas.">"; //only see "Array" written over the image
```

HTH,
TD